# Perl suppress backtick output with ping

Tags: perl, system, output, suppress

Suppressing system output from Perl code.

This code works fine functionally until I run into a hostname that can't resolved and want to suppress the output of a unresolvable domain.

If in the lists.hosts file there is a domain that can't be resolved, the screen output will contain: "ping: cannot resolve XXX.com: Unknown host"

```
my $ip;

open(HOSTLIST, "lists.hosts");    # Load domains
@hosts = <HOSTLIST>;
chomp($host);

foreach $host (@hosts) {

  $results = `ping -c 1 $host`;

  $record++;

  my $pos = index($results, $find);

  if (($results =~ /ttl=/) || ($results =~ /data bytes/)) {
    #$count++;
    chomp($host);
    if (($results =~ /(?<=bytes from)(.*)(?=:)/) != 0) {
      ($ip) = ($results =~ /(?<=bytes from)(.*)(?=:)/);
    }
    elsif (($results =~ /(?<=\()(.*)(?=\))/) != 0) {
      ($ip) = ($results =~ /(?<=\()(.*)(?=\))/);
    }

    print "Record: $record Host: $host IP:$ip Status: Passed";
    print "\n";

    #print ("*** Record# $record: Ping Test Succeeded for Server: $host ***\n");
    #print ("$results\n");
  }
  else {
    $count++;
    chomp($host);

    #print ("*** Record# $record: Ping Test Failed for Server: $host ***\n");
    print "Record: $record Host: $host Status: Failed\n";

    #print ("$results\n");
  }
}

close(HOSTLIST);

exit($errorcode);
```

Comment: Please *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the start of *every* Perl program you write. That applies especially when you are asking for help with your code. You should also indent your code properly so that it is readable. I have done it for you in this case, but you should do it for yourself as it will help you to see the flow of your code and make it simpler to spot any bugs

Answer (score 1):

Your invocation of `ping` needs to capture stderr:

```
ping -c 1 $host 2>&1
```

Also, you're not checking the return of your `open`, which you should do always.  Finally, you should be using `use warnings;` and `use strict;` at the top.

Comment: I did try sending stderr to null and still sends out the ping error